# Get difference between the value in one row and the next

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have some students with report marks over a number of reporting periods. I use the following SQL statement to get those report marks

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ID, thePeriod, MeritRank
 FROM   
 (
 SELECT ID, 
        cast(fileyear as varchar) + cast(filesemester as varchar)  as thePeriod, 
        MeritRank
 FROM uNCStudentMeritList) usm
 ORDER BY ID, thePeriod asc
```

This gives me the following data

[image: TableData]

I would love to have another column which has the difference between each row, partitioned by the ID number. For example

[image]

Note: the first value item for each StudentId is left blank as this is the first report mark they have received. From then on, I would like to see the difference between one report mark and the next. If they have received a worse report mark then it should be a negative figure as shown. I don't have row ID numbers or anything in the table - I have seen other similar types of questions answered using  row ID numbers. How can I get the sort of results I am after>

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? In 2012 you could use `LEAD`/`LAG` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
;WITH cte_getdata
     AS (SELECT ID,
                Cast(fileyear AS VARCHAR(10))
                + Cast(filesemester AS VARCHAR(10))                                                    AS thePeriod,
                MeritRank,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY id
                    ORDER BY Cast(fileyear AS VARCHAR(10)) ASC, Cast(filesemester AS VARCHAR(10)) ASC) AS rn
         FROM   uNCStudentMeritList)
SELECT t1.*,
       t1.MeritRank - t2.MeritRank
FROM   cte_getdata t1
       LEFT JOIN cte_getdata t2
              ON t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
                 AND t1.id = t2.id
```

The `Row_Number()` function will assign unique number to each record in partitions of `id` and order of `fileyear,filesemester` then you can `left join` the resultset with itself and match the current row with its previous row having same `id`. Using `Left Join` will give you all the rows regardless of matching condition. Here is a same approach with two `CTE` :

```
;WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT ID,
                Cast(fileyear AS VARCHAR)
                + Cast(filesemester AS VARCHAR) AS thePeriod,
                MeritRank
         FROM   uNCStudentMeritList),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY ID
                    ORDER BY thePeriod) rn
         FROM   cte1)
SELECT *
FROM   cte2 c1
       LEFT JOIN cte2 c2
              ON c1.id = c2.id
                 AND c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak. This doesn't seem to work that well - it seems to run continuously and I have to cancel the query. It produces a lot of data, most of it repeated. A note also - the rownumbers may not be contiguous - they may not be in order. Thanks for your help but any ideas?

Comment: @Barrelnc Sorry, my mistake. I forgot to add some criteria in join condition. check now...

Comment: Thanks so much Deepak -works really well. I put a line in at the end to order it by t1.id to keep the ID numbers together. Great solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER (partition BY id ORDER BY theperiod) rn,
                *
         FROM   tablename)
SELECT a.id,
       a.theperiod,
       a.MeritRank,
       a.MeritRank - b.MeritRank
FROM   cte A
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.rn = b.rn + 1
```

Or if you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` try this.

```
SELECT id,
       theperiod,
       MeritRank,
       Lag(MeritRank)
         OVER (
           partition BY id
           ORDER BY theperiod) - MeritRank
FROM   tablename
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using SQL 2012. I have tried your second example but I get "Invalid column name 'the_period'."  Do I need to use this just as a subquery? Sorry - fairly new to this and just not sure how to incorporate this into my original SQL.

Comment: @Barrelnc - Check now. It should be `theperiod` instead of `the_period`

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
SELECT usm1.ID, usm1.thePeriod, usm1.MeritRank, usm2.difference
FROM (SELECT ID, cast(fileyear as varchar) + cast(filesemester as varchar)  as thePeriod, MeritRank
      FROM uNCStudentMeritList)usm1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT usm3.ID as ID, usm3.thePeriod as thePeriod, max(usm4.thePeriod), (usm3.MeritRank - usm4.MeritRank) as difference 
      FROM (SELECT ID, cast(fileyear as varchar) + cast(filesemester as varchar)  as thePeriod, MeritRank
      FROM uNCStudentMeritList)usm3 JOIN 
      (SELECT ID, cast(fileyear as varchar) + cast(filesemester as varchar)  as thePeriod, MeritRank
      FROM uNCStudentMeritList)usm4 USING (ID) 
      WHERE usm3.thePeriod > usm4.thePeriod
      GROUP BY usm3.ID, usm3.thePeriod)usm2 USING (ID, thePeriod)
```

Comment: Thanks iris. It doesn't seem to like the 'USING' function. I keep getting 'Incorrect syntax near using' Any thoughts?

Comment: you can use join ... on (usm3.ID = usm4.ID) and join ... on  (usm4.ID = usm2.ID AND usm4.thePeriod = usm2.thePeriod) instead of using